MySQL Json field split into rows given the amount of keys
I am trying to split a json field into N amount of rows given the different elements that the field has.
Here is the query I'm using:
    WITH Jsonified AS (
    SELECT 
        test_json_data,
        CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(test_json_data, "\\'", "''"), "'", '"') as json) as json_data
    FROM vt_raw_data
    WHERE full_url = 'test'
)
SELECT 
    j.json_data,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(j.json_data), CONCAT('$[', idx, ']'))) AS `key`-- ,
    -- JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(j.json_data, CONCAT('$.', JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(j.json_data), CONCAT('$[', idx, ']')))))) AS `value`
FROM Jsonified j
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(j.json_data), '$[*]' COLUMNS (idx FOR ORDINALITY)) AS keys_idx;

And here is a sample of the data:
{'provider1': 'malicious', 'provider2': 'malware', 'provider3': 'malware'}

The issues I'm having are the following:

I am having three rows returned (as expected) but key for 3rd row is empty where it should be 'provider3'
I need to do the same for the value of the key, but I think solving point 1 I will be able to replicate

Thanks in advance!

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html says:

name FOR ORDINALITY: This type enumerates rows in the COLUMNS clause; the column named name is a counter whose type is UNSIGNED INT, and whose initial value is 1. This is equivalent to specifying a column as AUTO_INCREMENT in a CREATE TABLE statement, and can be used to distinguish parent rows with the same value for multiple rows generated by a NESTED [PATH] clause.

But https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html says:

[N] appended to a path that selects an array names the value at position N within the array. Array positions are integers beginning with zero.

(emphasis mine in both cases)
Your query works if you adjust for the off-by-one difference:
...CONCAT('$[', idx-1, ']')...

